# suppress/eliminate datagrip sql reformatting for nested selects

Tags: sql, datagrip, nested-select

In datagrip's SQL editor, if I start with a sql select like

```
select 
col1,
col2,
col3 
from table1
```

and then wrap it in parentheses in a nested select context, it resets all my lines, viz:

```
select
t1.*
from (
  select col1
    , col2
    , col3
  from table1
) t1
```

I hate this so much.  I would like it to behave something like:

```
select
t1.*
from 
(
select 
col1
,col2
,col3
from table1
) t1
```

The difference would be that it doesn't re-assign lines and indents for the nested select.  --I can take care of that myself.

Does anyone know how to turn off this wrapping/indenting behavior for nested selects?  I've messed with DG's preferences dialogue for some while but to no avail.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Could you reframe your question as expected results vs. obtained results?

Comment: @FranciscoHanna I have done so above per your request.  Thanks!

Comment: How do you wrap? By 'surround with' action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disble code formatting.

- Go to *File > Settings > Editor > Code Style*.
- Check the *Disable Formatting* option that's in bottom of the settings window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Francisco.  I had tried exactly that previously; it does not work for me.